# Is there a way to use a system like Term Store(SharePoint) in ServiceNow?

Tags: taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am looking to implement translated terms and reuse them inside ServiceNow platform. What is the equivalent of SharePoint Terms Store in ServiceNow?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of ways to localize text in ServiceNow to other languages. One way is to create alternate language labels for tables and fields using the Labels related list on the Dictionary Entry form. Perhaps the closest equivalent to the SharePoint Term Store would be the Messages [sys_ui_message] table. You can provide translations for messages in various languages, then when you call `gs.getMessage('your message here')` the logged in user will get the appropriate message for their preferred language.

This documentation page provides more information and examples: [ServiceNow Product Documentation › Custom Translations](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/tokyo-platform-administration/page/administer/localization/concept/translating-applications.html). Hope it helps!